# Google Places iOS - App size is too large

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api

I want to integrate the google places autocomplete service, in an iOS app. The problem with Google Maps SDK for iOS is the size of library. After install Google Maps(include Places) the increased the size to 130MB (before only 25MB).

My question is: is there some way to reduce that size? if not, how is a better solution to looking for an address? (with autocomplete)

Regards

Comment: Same problem with me , i am using it with pods  file and the project size is 160 mb and the build file is also 39 mb ..if you know the solution please suggest

Comment: Note that the Google Places SDK for iOS is now in a separate Cocoapod to Maps, and significantly smaller. See https://developers.google.com/places/migrate-to-v2 for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are concerned with the application's size, not the project.

The 130MB is the size of your project, not your Product/App. You can check the size of the app in your iPhone settings or if you use simulator:

/Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[simulator version]/Applications/[appfolder]/[product name]

If you are concerned with the project's size you could use Swift solution instead of downloading the whole Google Places API:
https://github.com/watsonbox/ios_google_places_autocomplete

Answer (score 1):

To check the file size of the app in Xcode 8 and up.

First go to

> ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/

and delete complete folder and build the application. Now you only have two folders specifically related to your current app.

First folder is the one in which you should be interested.

> [First folder]/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/[Application
>   ID]/[app Name]